# Undesired new page with fullwidth, framebox, and enumerate

Tags: enumerate, geometry, framed, fullwidth

How can I prevent question 3 from being pushed to the third page here?  What causes this anomalous behavior?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullwidth}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\answerspace}[1]{\begin{fullwidth}[width=\textwidth,skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=10pt]\framebox[\textwidth]{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{#1}}\end{fullwidth}}%

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item What is 1+1?
\answerspace{3cm}
    \item What is 2+1?
\answerspace{5cm}
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you rely on  `fullwidth`? Package `exsheets` provides a command that does what you want. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Teacher%27s_Corner#Exsheets

Comment: Thanks @Johannes_B.  I'm happy to get rid of `fullwidth` but `exsheets` seems overkill.

Comment: To be clear: I want the box to be full width.  And yes, I know I can jump out of `enumerate' and resume using `enumitem` but since I could be three levels deep, this would be a serious pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{indentlevel}
\newcommand{\answerspace}[1]{\setlength{\parindent}{-\value{indentlevel}\leftmargin}\par\framebox[\textwidth]{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{0pt}{#1}}\par}%

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\begin{enumerate}[before*=\stepcounter{indentlevel},after*=\addtocounter{indentlevel}{-1}]
    \item What is 1+1?
\answerspace{3cm}
    \item What is 2+1?
\answerspace{5cm}
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```